# First element of NSDictionary is <null> instead of 1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, snapshot

Via Firebase I get data out of Database, see the data on picture
[image]

**Edited:** When I print the snapshot.value like here:

```
DBProvider.Instance.dbRef.child("driverLocations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.value!)
   }
}
```

I get:

```
(
"<null>",
    {
    driverName = chauffeur1;
    latitude = "37.33756603";
    longitude = "-122.04120235";
  }
)
```

Where  stands, It should be 1. Does anybody know this problem?

**It only happens when I use 1, when I use 2 or other numbers, I don't get the** 
I'll be glad to know :)

Comment: My guess is that 1 is defined has a number, and not has a string. Try replacing `[String:[String:Any]]` with `[Int:[String:Any]]`.

Comment: @vitormm I'm sorry, I copied the wrong section. Please see updated version.

Comment: @vitormm It only happens when the number is 1...

Comment: Maybe it's a mistake in Firebase's side. What do you get if you use `[Any:[String:Any]]`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the  problem by using numbers as 01 - 02 - 03 instead of 1 - 2- -3. This solved the problem, really weird workingaround tho..